# Is there any method to fill a Rect in a Canvas with an image?

Tags: java, android

I've setted up a simple application that once I have structured a Canvas puts an Rectangle inside it. I was asking myself if there's a method that allows me to fill that rettangle with an image.

This is my Canvas Class code:

```
public class MioCanvas extends View {

    Paint paint;
    Rect rect;

    public MioCanvas(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        rect = new Rect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 1999999, canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, paint);
    }
}
```

This is my activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MioCanvas mioCanvas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mioCanvas = new MioCanvas(this);
        mioCanvas.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        setContentView(mioCanvas);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Bitmap with your custom rect as input.

```
  Rect rectangle = new Rect(0,0,100,100);
   canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rectangle, null);
```